# Azure to IIS on premises hosting

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an app (developed not by me) built in c#.net with visual studio 2015 that needs to be pulled out of azure and host the app in house on one of the servers for cost cutting.

Now the architecture of the app is designed to host in azure. Its using tableentity in azure, blob storage, queues through a worker role.

I was looking for the easiest way to strip all the off and use file system, local SQL server and host it in IIS. What steps can I take to remove the worker role and how to host in IIS.

The app is has got 8 services (projects), they are calling each other through Azure service bus. All services are using service bus queues in worker role and listening for the input message.

What can I replace the azure service bus queues with on IIS - windows 2008 R2 server.

thanks

Comment: Also what is the nearest technique that I can use to Windows Azure Service bus, are there any plugins for Windows server that I can just publish the code to windows server. Can I replace the azure service bus end points with windows server service bus 1.1 end points and it will all work? What do I need to do? Any direction pls?